# Possible to upload Fonts in Sharepoint modern site?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

**Is it possible to upload font files to SharePoint online?**

I would like to use a corporate font in SharePoint sites. I have the font files, it just doesn’t seem to be a way to upload and register them in SPO.

**In case it is possible, is it recommended by Microsoft?**

Answer (score 0):

The font scheme files are located in the 15 subfolder of the Theme Gallery of the root site of the site collection. You can directly navigate to the URL: http://SiteCollectionName/_catalogs/theme/15/.
Then you could upload the font files over here.

Please check this article for more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/color-palettes-and-fonts-in-sharepoint?#Fontschemes